# Pagination for the view which is not using the EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add pagination to the Index()/ the view , this index view uses the custom Model this is not a table from the DB. I am trying to see if I can use the PaginatedList.cs, as my other pages in the same project uses the EF and have pagination working great.

Below is is my index()

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string custEmail,int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        List<Order> oo = new List<Order>();

        var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

        var orderData = from mo in _context.MouseOrders
                        join io in _context.InventoryOrders on mo.MouseOrderId equals io.OrderId
                        join cus in _context.Customers on mo.CustomerId equals cus.CustomerId
                        join i in _context.Inventories on io.InventoryId  equals i.InventoryId
                        where mo.SamaccountEmail == custEmail 
                        && mo.OrderDate.Date == todayDt.Date
                        select new
                        {
                           CustomerNumber= cus.CustomerNumber,
                           OrderID = mo.MouseOrderId,
                           Genotype = i.Genotype,
                            RoomNumber = i.RoomNumber,
                            QuantityAvailable = i.QuantityAvailable,
                            OrderQuantity = io.OrderQuantity
                        };

       foreach (var item in orderData)
        {
            Order o = new Order();
            o.CustomerNumber = item.CustomerNumber;
            o.OrderId = item.OrderID;
            o.Genotype = item.Genotype;
            o.RoomNumber = item.RoomNumber;
            o.QuantityAvailable = item.QuantityAvailable;
            o.OrderQuantity = item.OrderQuantity;
            oo.Add(o);
        }
        return View(await PaginatedList<Order>.CreateAsync(oo,pageNumber,5));
    }
```

But I get error like

`Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<JSMApp.Models.Order>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<JSMApp.Models.Order>'`

I tried changing the List `List<Order>` to IQueryable but even that is throwing error.

I am trying to have the same pagination behavior/look and feel that I have for the other pages that uses the EF and PaginatedList but not sure how to do for the Models that are custom and not from DB

*****EDIT******
When I am trying to access the Index() page I am getting the below error

`An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. JSMApp.PaginatedList<T>.CreateAsync<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> entities, int v, int pageSize) in PaginatedList.cs, line 53`

Below is the line where it is throowing the error in PaginatedList

```
 internal static Task<string> CreateAsync<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> entities, int v, int pageSize) where TEntity : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: You can simply query the DB model then map that model to view model in the Index method.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to follow you. My querying and all works but I am unable to do the pagination. If you see the the above query has to pull data from different tables

Comment: You are creating an anonymous type in your projection `select new {...}`. But it looks like you can just create an Order `select new Order{...}`. Then the `IQueryable<Order> orderData` can be passed to `PaginatedList`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman But how can I map the fields from the joined tables to the Order? Can you please give me an example

Comment: With standard member initialisation. The syntax doesn't change from what you already have. `CustomerNumber  = cus.CustomerNumber, ...`

Comment: If order is not a DB model then this approach will not work. Alternatively, you can consider store procedure for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Does that mean I dont need to convert the orderDate to the List<order>

Comment: It doesn't matter if `Order` is just some random object, unrelated to your context. If you construct a class / struct in your projection, then EF Core will generate the sql and a factory method to turn a database reader into an enumerable of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just change;

```cs
select new
{
    CustomerNumber= cus.CustomerNumber,
    OrderID = mo.MouseOrderId,
    // etc
}
```

to

```cs
select new Order
{
    CustomerNumber= cus.CustomerNumber,
    OrderID = mo.MouseOrderId,
    // etc
}
```

Now your `orderData` will be an `IQueryable<Order>` that can be passed;

```cs
PaginatedList<Order>.CreateAsync(orderData,pageNumber,5))
```

Comment: Mind you, you could create a paginated list from your anonymous type instead. But I don't think you can define a view model based on that.

Comment: Thank you but I am running to error, added the screenshot of the error

Comment: What is `JAXSurplusMouseApp`? Is that your source code? So why is your CreateAsync method throwing not implemented? (But also, don't post text as an image..)